# How to enable source package download for a section of private ubuntu repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, repository

We have created a internal ubuntu repository. It has a few custom sections which has packages that were custom built. Currently, no source packages are provided for download for the repository users.

We would like to have source packages available for few sections in the local ubuntu repositories, so that users will be able to download the packages only from them and not from other sections.

What is the easiest way of doing it?